# Having trouble getting TensorFlow to do something trivial

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a vector x and want to compute a vector y such that `y[j] = x[j]**2` using a neural network specified by TensorFlow, below.  It doesn't work so well, the error is high.
Am I doing something wrong?
Any help will be appreciated

The way it works is it first generates data in Xtrain, Ytrain, Xtest, and Ytest and then creates placeholder variables to get TensorFlow going.
Then it specifies three hidden layers and one output layer.  Then it trains, and Ypred, the prediction for Ytest, is created using a feed dictionary.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

n = 10
k = 1000
n_hidden = 10
learning_rate = .01
training_epochs = 100000

Xtrain = []
Ytrain = []
Xtest = []
Ytest = []

for i in range(0,k,1):
    X = np.random.randn(1,n)[0]
    Xtrain += [X]
    Ytrain += [Xtrain[-1]**2]
    X = np.random.randn(1,n)[0]
    Xtest += [X]
    Ytest += [Xtest[-1]**2]

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float64,shape = (k,n))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float64,shape = (k,n))

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((n,n_hidden),dtype = tf.float64))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((n_hidden,),dtype = tf.float64))
x_hidden1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x,W1) + b1)

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((n,n_hidden),dtype = tf.float64))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((n_hidden,),dtype = tf.float64))
x_hidden2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x_hidden1,W2) + b2)

W3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((n,n_hidden),dtype = tf.float64))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((n_hidden,),dtype = tf.float64))
x_hidden3 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x_hidden1,W3) + b3)

W4 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((n,n_hidden),dtype = tf.float64))
b4 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((n_hidden,),dtype = tf.float64))
y_pred = tf.matmul(x_hidden3,W4) + b4

penalty = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs((y - y_pred)))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(penalty)

model = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(model)
    for i in range(0,training_epochs):
        sess.run(train_op,{x: Xtrain,y: Ytrain})

    Ypred = y_pred.eval(feed_dict = {x: Xtest})
```

Comment: This might belong on the [Stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) site. I have a hunch that the issue is going to be more theoretical than technical.

Answer (score 0):

Here is just some simple modification of your code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

n = 10
k = 1000
learning_rate = 1e-3
training_epochs = 100000

# It will be better for you to use PEP8 style

# None here will allow you to feed data with ANY k size
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=(None, n))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=(None, n))

# Use default layer constructors
# from your implementation it uses another random initializer
out = tf.layers.dense(x, 100)
out = tf.layers.batch_normalization(out)
# ReLU is better than sigmoid, there are a lot of articles about it
out = tf.nn.relu(out)

out = tf.layers.dense(out, 200)
out = tf.layers.batch_normalization(out)
out = tf.nn.relu(out)

out = tf.layers.dense(out, n)

# total loss = mean L1 for samples
# each sample is a vector of 10 values, so you need to calculate
# sum along first axis, and them calculate mean of sums
l1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(y - out), axis=1))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(l1)

model = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(model)
    for i in range(training_epochs):
        xs = np.random.randn(k, n)
        ys = xs ** 2
        _, l1_value = sess.run(
            [train_op, l1],
            feed_dict={x: xs, y: ys})
        if (i + 1) % 10000 == 0 or i == 0:
            print('Current l1({}/{}) = {}'.format(
                i + 1, training_epochs, l1_value))

    xs = np.random.randn(k, n)
    ys = xs ** 2
    test_l1 = sess.run(l1, feed_dict={x: xs, y: ys})
    print ('Total l1 at test = {}'.format(test_l1))
```

Output:

```
Current l1(1/100000) = 11.0853215657
Current l1(10000/100000) = 0.126037403282
Current l1(20000/100000) = 0.096445475666
Current l1(30000/100000) = 0.0719392853473
Current l1(40000/100000) = 0.0690671103719
Current l1(50000/100000) = 0.07661241544
Current l1(60000/100000) = 0.0743827124406
Current l1(70000/100000) = 0.0656016587469
Current l1(80000/100000) = 0.0675546809828
Current l1(90000/100000) = 0.0649035400487
Current l1(100000/100000) = 0.0583308788607
Total l1 at test = 0.0613149096968
```

Total penalty may be enhanced using some other architecture, learning rate, batch size, count of epochs, loss function, e.t.c.

It looks that architecture may be increased, then you will be able to run training for a long period of time to get 1e-3.

More information about how it works and how to do it you can find at [CS231 course](http://cs231n.github.io/).

P.S. here is some assumption about data feeding: some data on which I tested might was at the training process. Because task is simple it's OK, but it's better to guarantee, that not any train sample will be in test set.

Comment: I'm already getting errors of about 0.44, so this isn't that big an improvement.  Does anyone know what really will get the error down to 1e-3?

Comment: @user3692990, it seems that it's necessary to spend a lot of time on train to get it. Look at update.

Comment: This was very helpful, I appreciate it.  It seems that of the several changes that you made, using more variables per hidden layer is really what did it.  I'm going to post updated code once I'm done tinkering.

Answer (score 0):

This code does a lot better.  Anyone want to make any further improvements?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

n = 10
k = 1000
n_hidden = 50
learning_rate = .001
training_epochs = 100000

Xtrain = []
Ytrain = []
Xtest = []
Ytest = []

for i in range(0,k,1):
    X = np.random.randn(1,n)[0]
    Xtrain += [X]
    Ytrain += [Xtrain[-1]**2]
    X = np.random.randn(1,n)[0]
    Xtest += [X]
    Ytest += [Xtest[-1]**2]

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float64,shape = (k,n))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float64,shape = (k,n))

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((n,n_hidden),dtype = tf.float64))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((n_hidden,),dtype = tf.float64))
x_hidden1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x,W1) + b1)

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((n_hidden,n_hidden),dtype = tf.float64))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((n_hidden,),dtype = tf.float64))
x_hidden2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x_hidden1,W2) + b2)

W3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((n_hidden,n),dtype = tf.float64))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((n,),dtype = tf.float64))
y_pred = tf.matmul(x_hidden2,W3) + b3

penalty = tf.reduce_sum((y - y_pred)**2)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(penalty)

model = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(model)
    for i in range(0,training_epochs):
        sess.run(train_op,{x: Xtrain,y: Ytrain})

    Ypred = y_pred.eval(feed_dict = {x: Xtest})
```